# How to change border of image in button on press using SwiftUI?

Tags: animation, button, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a NavigationLink composed of an image and some text, I would like to change the border colour of the image when the link is pressed.

Here is the NavigationLink:

```
NavigationLink(destination: TrickSelectView()) {
    HStack{
        Image("learnTricksButton")
            .resizable()
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color(red: 0.95, green: 0.32, blue: 0.34), lineWidth: 4))
            .shadow(radius: 7)
            .frame(width: width, height: width)
                                
         VStack{
            Text("Trick")
                .font(.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded))
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.13, green: 0.15, blue: 0.22))

            Text("Personalise your learning!")
                .font(.system(.subheadline, design: .rounded))
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.28, green: 0.32, blue: 0.37))
          }
     }.padding(.bottom, 50)
}.buttonStyle(LearnButtonEffect())
```

And here is what I got so far for the Button Style:

```
struct LearnButtonEffect: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .background(configuration.isPressed ? Color.green.opacity(0.5) : Color.green)
            .shadow(color: Color.gray, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.9 : 1.0)
    }
}
```

In general I want to know how I can reference a specific part of the NavigationLink (in this case the border of the image) in the Button Style definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PrimitiveButtonStyle` and pass a specific view and perform your action.

Here is the demo:

Create a style

```
struct LearnButtonEffectButtonStyle: PrimitiveButtonStyle {
    var image: Image
    var action: () -> Void
    
    func makeBody(configuration: PrimitiveButtonStyle.Configuration) -> some View {
        ButtonView(configuration: configuration, image: image, action: action)
    }
    
    struct ButtonView: View {
        @State private var pressed = false
        
        let configuration: PrimitiveButtonStyle.Configuration
        let image: Image
        var action: () -> Void
        
        var body: some View {
            return HStack{
                image
                    .resizable()
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .overlay(Circle().stroke(self.pressed ? Color.yellow : Color.blue, lineWidth: 4)) // <<- You can change here .overlay(Circle().stroke(self.pressed ? Color.yellow : Color.blue, lineWidth: 4))
                    .shadow(radius: 7)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                    .border(self.pressed ? Color.yellow : Color.blue, width: 2) //<<- remove it if not required
                configuration.label
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 50)
            .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.2, maximumDistance: .infinity, pressing: { pressing in
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2)) {
                    self.pressed = pressing
                }
                if !pressing {
                    action()
                }
            }, perform: {
                print("Perform")
            })
            .background(self.pressed ? Color.green.opacity(0.5) : Color.green)
            .shadow(color: Color.gray, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
            .scaleEffect(self.pressed ? 0.9 : 1.0)
        }
    }
}
```

How to use?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isActive = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("test"), isActive: $isActive) {
                VStack{
                    Text("Trick")
                        .font(.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded))
                        .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.13, green: 0.15, blue: 0.22))
                    
                    Text("Personalise your learning!")
                        .font(.system(.subheadline, design: .rounded))
                        .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.28, green: 0.32, blue: 0.37))
                }
            }.buttonStyle(LearnButtonEffectButtonStyle(image: Image("learnTricksButton"), action: {
                self.isActive.toggle()
            }))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since In SwiftUI we ***do not keep any reference*** to any of Views. Instead we change the value(`@State`, `@Binding`, `@ObservableObject`, `@StatObject` ..) the view is reflected.

```swift
 struct ContentView: View {
        @State var isActive = false //To start navigation
        @State var isClicked = false //to track wather click
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text("Destination"),
                    isActive: $isActive,
                    label: {
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            isActive = true
                            isClicked = true
                        }, label: {
                            HStack{
                                Image("learnTricksButton")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .clipShape(Circle())
                                    .overlay(Circle().stroke(isClicked ? Color.black:Color(red: 0.95, green: 0.32, blue: 0.34), lineWidth: 4))
                                    .shadow(radius: 7)
                                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                
                                VStack{
                                    Text("Trick")
                                        .font(.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded))
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.13, green: 0.15, blue: 0.22))
                                    
                                    Text("Personalise your learning!")
                                        .font(.system(.subheadline, design: .rounded))
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.28, green: 0.32, blue: 0.37))
                                }
                            }.padding(.bottom, 50)
                        })
                        
                    })
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think OP wants the only image, not a whole button.

Comment: @RajaKishan yes